# What is the meaning of an opaque pixel format

Tags: android

In android, I can set a surface to OPAQUE pixel format

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html

Can you please tell me what does OPAQUE format means?
Does it mean raw, no encoding format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Opaque pixel format is basically associated with determining pixels transparency / opaqueness. Usually the [alpha channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_channel) is used as an opacity channel. By Setting the Pixel format to OPAQUE Android will choose its own OPAQUE format rather than using the Alpha channel bits for transparency information.

Also read [RGBA color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) for more information.